# How can I avoid using goto for a series of prompts?

Tags: goto

I'm writing a console based application that prompts a user for a series of questions. E.g:

"Enter a record to open:"

"Do you want to do X?"

"Do you want to do Y?"

"Are you sure you want to continue?"

If the user enters nothing at any prompt I want to go up one level. This is easy using goto. The only other way I can think of to do it is nested for loops which looks *far* uglier and gets pretty unwieldy for more than a couple of prompts. There must be an easy way to do this though, I just can't think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically writing a very simple state machine - use functions to represent every state: (I'll use random pseudocode, since you didn't specify a language)

```
get_information():
    return get_record()

ask_record():
    record = read_line()
    return () if !record
    return ask_y(record)

ask_x(record):
    x = read_line()
    return ask_record() if !x
    return ask_y(record, x)

ask_y(record, x):
    y = read_line()
    return ask_x(record) if !y
    return ask_continue(record, x, y)

ask_continue(record, x, y)
    continue = read_line()
    return ask_y(record, x) if !continue
    return (record, x, y)
```

this is a trivial approach. In some languages the call stack will grow, in others it won't. If you have a language which causes the stack to grow, you can use trampolines to prevent it, by rewriting `get_information` to do:

```
x = get_information
while x is function:
    x=x()
return x

ask_x(record):
    x = read_line()
    return (lambda: ask_record()) if !x
    return (lambda: ask_y(record, x))
```

Or even abstracting the question and memory address of result in some `question` structure:

```
struct question {
    question *next, *prev;
    char prompt[];
    char **result;
}
```

and then running in a loop, calling `question* run_question(question*)`, going to ->next, or ->prev depending on the answer, until the result is NULL (as a stop condition, when results are filled in and no questions are left).

The last solution is probably the most "normal one" if you use an imperative language with direct pointer access.

Answer (score 1):

Write it recursively instead of iteratively.

Comment: Isn't this kind of what the for loop does (i.e. require multiple levels of nesting)?

Answer (score 1):

write it as a simple state machine.

```
while(running)
{
    if (state == INIT)
    {
        out("enter record");
        state = DO_X;
    }
    else if (state == DO_X)
    {
        do whatever for x.
        state = WHATEVER_NEXT_STATE_IS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, although I hate code written *this way*. You cannot split it easily when it grows. You cannot make it modular and plug in a new path with change of one line and a new library. You cannot easily find what links where after you reach >10 states. General idea is good though.